# vb.net: logging off an rdp session will not trigger on_Disconnect event

Tags: vb.net, rdp

I have a 2 form RDP application that functions (connects/works) fine.  The first form allows for entry of data (server name, user, password) and passes this data to a second form that runs the RDP control in full screen.  There are no other controls on the second form.  The form containing the RDP control does not contain the MIN/MAX/X box, by design, ie, the app is full screen, no borders.

My issue is that when the user logs off the RDP session (click START/Log off), the on_Disconnected event is not triggered in the form that holds the RDP control.  I am left with an open form with no way to close it, other than manually from the taskbar.  I'd like to run this code, but the onDisconnected event doesn't generate:

```
'     <from the form containing the RDP (rdp2) control>

Private Sub rdp2_OnDisconnected(sender As Object, e As IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent) Handles rdp2.OnDisconnected
         'closes RDP window after log out
    me.close
    frmStart.Show()
End Sub
```

I also tried the onConfirmClose event, with the same result. Of course, if I kept the border and the MIN/MAX/X, I could close the form manually.
Is there another event or another method to recognize the Log out from the session?  I couldn't find documentation that fits here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the same problem happened on my way.
I chose to implement the version 9 of TSC control, available in my case in VS2015:

```
Imports AxMSTSCLib
Dim rdp As New AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting
```

Then you can notice that the client9 has more properties:

```
    Private Sub RDP_Disconnected(sender As Object, e As IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent)

    If CType(sender, AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting).ExtendedDisconnectReason = ExtendedDisconnectReasonCode.exDiscReasonAPIInitiatedLogoff Or CType(sender, AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting).ExtendedDisconnectReason = ExtendedDisconnectReasonCode.exDiscReasonLogoffByUser Then
        CType(sender, AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting).Tag = "Logoff"

    End If
end sub
```

The useful one: ExtendedDisconnectReason, you can check it on disconnected event.

BR1